# TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('|S6') and format specifier ('%.18e')

Tags: python, numpy

I get this type error when trying to write using numpy.savetxt with this numpy array:

```
predictions = array([b'5712.3', b'2058.0', b'834.03', b'535.63', ...
   b'8796.2', b'9593.0'], dtype='|S6')

np.savetxt('test.txt', predictions, newline=" ")
```

I can't find anything useful in the docs and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't format strings using the "%e" specifier. For example, `print '%e' % ('hello')` will produce a `TypeError`. By default arrays passed to `np.savetxt` will be formatted using `'%.18e'` (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html). You can change the format specifier or save your array as floats.